# View Cube - user specified labels

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, eyeshot

I want to change the View Cube labels in the Eyeshot model.

E.g. The user should be able to change the "S" direction to just what pleases the user.

**What I have done**

In the xaml I have accessed the "FrontRingLabel" and then bind it to "FrontRingUserInput" which should be a **char**.

```
<ddes:Viewport.ViewCubeIcon>
<ddes:ViewCubeIcon Lighting="False" ShowRing="True" FrontRingLabel="{Binding FrontRingUserInput}" />
</ddes:Viewport.ViewCubeIcon>
```

Then I try to set the value which i want to display:

```
public char FrontRingUserInput
{
   get { return 'south'; }

   set { }

}
```

**The error**
CS1012 C# Too many characters in character literal

Any ideas, or alternativ solutions in how to set the view cube labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are saying your property returns `char` which is of 1 byte but you are actually trying to return a `string`

```
public char FrontRingUserInput
{
   get { return 'south'; } // "south" is not 1 byte and thus is not char. So the error
```

You probably want to change the type of the property to `string`

```
public string FrontRingUserInput
{
   get { return "south"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahul!

I was not aware of that. Chaning it to a string or char of only one letter actually worked!

**Alternative solution**

However the FrontRingLabel of the View Cube is of type char, and therefore when I enter a string of more then one letter it do not appear. Since I need more then one letter my solution is to remove the ring and change the label of the facades of the cube since they take more then one letter (see [this image])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSspc.png).

Comment: Looking at the image, maybe you need to change FrontText property instead of FrontRingLabel